# I get the following message on my phone: "confirm if it's you recovering your account"

Tags: security, google-account

But I didn't do any recovery and of course I didn't press any button.

It happened already two times.

What does it mean? Does somebody is trying to hack my google account?

I have 2 factor google authentification, but didn't get any SMS, which is supposed happens if somebody is trying to change my password.

I found the following discussions on:

[google community](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/8337105?hl=en)

[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GMail/comments/e2f5cf/confirm_if_its_you_recovering_your_account/)

but it isn't clear for me what does it mean and what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you were actually trying to [recover your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en), you should have received such a message.
- You didn't, and it looks like a glitch as the Google help you linked suggests.
- One option is do nothing, a better option would be review [your account](https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source=my-activity&utm_medium=home&utm_campaign&hl=en), sign out of unused devices, and change the Google password to a *strong* one. This question from our sister site is useful [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase/6116#6116). Generate new 2FA codes, keep them securely.
- Obviously, the second option is better because, you did a security check and changed passwords / 2 FA codes. As an added precaution, be on the lookout for Google security mails in your inbox.